# DNN 9.4.1 is not showing any Pages on the Persona Menu Bar

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I have a problem whereby the Pages in DNN is not showing when logged in.

I have attempted to look at the permissions in the database, but could not find anything.
I did attempt to add an upgrade package to the installation to see if this fixes the issue, but nothing.

Any ideas of what it could be and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/issues/2902

We went to https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/download and got the latest DNN Upgrade Package and only re-installed the Dnn.PersonaBar.UI_09.04.01_install.zip file via the Extensions on DotNetNuke. After the installation, we just had to Clear the Cache under Settings > Server.

[image]

The txt file in this folder had a typo which was .dl and not .dll for the pages section.